# Getting text from <li>´s & check duplicates & .append it... by jQuery

Tags: jquery, text, get, duplicates

HTML :

```
<li>Tue, 15th May 2012 10:11</li>
<li>Tue, 15th May 2012 10:12</li>
<li>Tue, 15th May 2012 10:13</li>
<li>Tue, 15th May 2012 10:14</li>
<li>Tue, 15th May 2012 10:15</li>
<li>Tue, 16th May 2012 21:08</li>
<li>Tue, 16th May 2012 21:07</li>
<li>Tue, 16th May 2012 21:06</li>
<code></code>
```

jQuery :

```
$("li").each(function () {
    words = $(this).text().split(' ');
    xxx = words[1]+" "+words[2]+" "+words[3]+",";
    $("code").append(xxx); 
});
```

I come to this step now, but i dont know how to check duplicates date and append unique date

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/4kvUy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this way:-

```
if ($("code:contains('"+xxx+"')").length == 0)
   $("code").append(xxx);
```

### EDIT:

To handle Comma, try this way:-

```
if ($("code:contains('"+xxx+"')").length == 0){
    if ($("code").text() == '')
        $("code").append(xxx);
    else
        $("code").append(","+xxx);
}
```

### EDIT2:

To handle this type of output, try this way:-

```
$("li").each(function () {
    words = $(this).text().split(' ');
    xxx = words[1]+" "+words[2]+" "+words[3];
    if ($("code:contains('"+xxx+"')").length == 0){     
        if ($("code").text() == '')         
            $("code").append('["'+xxx);     
        else         
            $("code").append('","'+xxx); 
    }
});
$("code").append('"]');
```

**Output:**

```
["15th May 2012","16th May 2012"]
```

Comment: one thing if i need to output like this : ["15th May 2012","10th May 2012"]

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector.

```
$("li").each(function() {
    words = $(this).text().split(' ');
    xxx = words[1] + " " + words[2] + " " + words[3] + ",";
    $("code:not(:contains(" + xxx + "))").append(xxx);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/4kvUy/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try [this on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/parush/4kvUy/4/), it seems to work.